# meaning of "attempted together "

Tags: meaning

What does "attempted together" mean in the following sentence.

> The problems of all the stages attempted together are enough to swamp anyone.

Also please clarify whether it refers to the stages or the problems.

Comment: We're going to need more context in order provide any kind of reliable answer.  Please quote the context in which this language appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to both the multiple stages and to the multiple problems, and means:

when considered or worked on - all together - at the same time - all the problems at all levels - present too great a difficulty - for any person to successfully repair

Solution:

Take apart or decompose the problems at each level and repair them separately

Answer (score 0):

Two important markers are 'The problems' (not 'The problem') and 'all the stages' (not 'all stages') indicate that it is cumulative problems and not the stages.  'The problems of all stages attempted together' indicate that the problems is more with 'attempting together' and not of individual stage, per se.